# How do I create a test account in adwords

Tags: google-ads-api

I am trying to work with google adwords API. I was able to optain a developer key, but I simply can't create my test account from manager one. I didn't connect the production account to manager one may be that is an issue. All I see in account types while creating new account is only addword one but no option for test. I wander how to create it. Documentation says nothin

Comment: Best place to ask a question of this topic is [Webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/). Please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) to find out which topics are covered here.

Answer (score 1):

Well I got it. I had to create a new adwords account on an other email address and not fund it at all and then it becomes a test account. There for I can use my api key wich is not approved in google against this account.

Comment: happy you sort out there :D

Answer (score 0):

Try this [link](https://www.webucator.com/how-to/how-create-google-adwords-account.cfm)
or this [link](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/guides/signup)
See that if it helps you

However, **StackOverflow** is a platform for asking programming question, You may post identical question type to other platform (For example SEO → [ProWebmaster](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/))for the next time :D

Comment: That why I am asking here. Sorry I don't need to create a new google account I need to optain an api key :)

Comment: @user13811451 is this link helps? https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/guides/signup
I think you are required a Google account no matter what 

Comment: I already have one. And yes. I rad this. It simply doesn't work.

Comment: @user13811451 you may try to dig more link as https://www.jcchouinard.com/adwords-api-request/ for me it just worked

Comment: Does it mean that I can start develope now and no test account is required? Only make an Oauth key for manager?

Comment: But it is strange. Because in form that you should apply for basic access account I see this https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/guides/accounts-overview#test_accounts But in managing account no such a word test account

Comment: @user13811451 hm... I am not sure about that, I never been there before, I think I can't help